# Accept returning socket ID of 0 -- Is it expected?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I was debugging something since last two days and it seems on my linux m/c accept is returning me a socket ID of zero.

```
       fd = accept(unix_domain_socket,
                   (struct sockaddr *) &new_connection,
                   &new_conn_length);
```

I see that fd is returning 0 -- Is this valid? Is 0 a valid socket fd number?

Comment: "man 2 accept" on my Debian system says "On success, these system calls return a nonnegative integer that is a descriptor for the accepted socket."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. -1 means that it failed, but 0 is valid. Usually file descriptor zero is occupied by the standard input, though.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, in my case i the stdin has been closed (process running as a daemon) so linux picks up the first free socket fd. Is there a way to instruct  linux to NOT pick up fd 0?

Comment: @Abhishek: The only way is to make sure fd 0 is used by something else.  If not stdin, then you can use `dup2(open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY), 0)` to close whatever is currently on 0 (if anything) and point it at /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

Any non-negative value is success.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be expected.
Usually a process by default open below fds with indexes:

```
0 : stdin
1 : stdout
2 : stderr
```

If your process has closed fd '0' deliberately or by mistake, then the next fd request can pick 0th index.